# Deploying a Selenium test and a wildfly server at the same time

Tags: java, maven, selenium, jenkins, wildfly

I'm trying to set up an automation project on Jenkins but having some issues. Things I need to do in order:

1. First, do a mvn install in 3 folders.
2. Run the wildfly server with a custom config file.
3. Run a .sh file from the project.
4. And last, run the tests.

My issue is, I can't deploy the server in the same Jenkins config but I have no idea on how to do it in another config. I need it so both of these run at the same time when one of them is triggered.